# How do I view the visitors who refresh a page using Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

The homepage of my website is a form (like Google's homepage) that sends the user to the same page once it's submitted. In other words, when the form is submitted, the page basically refreshes and loads something else.

Using Google Analytics, I can tell that a lot of people are exiting from my homepage. I want to find out if they're exiting before or after submitting the form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users are coming to your homepage directly, you can check the difference between the bounce rate and the exit rate. A bounce occurs when someone views a single page on the site and then leaves. So if they are submitting the form they shouldn't be bouncing but rather exiting.

You can also setup a funneled goal. Basically you'd setup a goal based on destination (your homepage) and then select to have a one step funnel that would also be your homepage. I haven't tested this but if it works like the documentation states then the goal should only be reported when users go from your homepage to your homepage (eventually)...

I'd suggest adding a query-string parameter to the form `action` so you can easily see when people are viewing your homepage after submitting the form. If your action is like this:

```
<form action="/index.php" ...
```

then change it to something like:

```
<form action="index.php?form=submitted" ...
```

I think this is the easiest way to track which data is being displayed on a page. Another method would be to use a custom bit of JS that reports the URL of the page to Google, so you can append the query-string parameter transparently to the user or even use a different file name in the URL.

When I take-over a site and AJAX-ify it, I normally use a combination of query-string parameters and custom reporting to Google (in JS) to mimic regular page-views so that analytics make sense for both versions of the site (meaning good time-over-time reports can be had).